# ¿Como importar datos del excel considerando la primera fila que no tienen encabezado en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, importación

Para poder importar datos desde excel uso el siguiente codigo:

```
Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Importados/");

fileuploader.SaveAs(Foldername + filename.ToString());

String conStr = "";
switch (Extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
        conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                 "Data Source=" + Foldername + "" + filename + ";" +
                 "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        break;

    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
        conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                 "Data Source=" + Foldername + "" + filename + ";" +
                 "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" +
                            "";
        break;
}
OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand();
//oconn.ConnectionString = conStr;
string conect = oconn.ConnectionString;

OleDbDataAdapter oDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
oconn.ConnectionString = conStr;
oconn.Open();
oCmd.CommandText = "select * from [Hoja1$]";
oCmd.Connection = oconn;
oDa.SelectCommand = oCmd;
oDa.Fill(oDs);
int fila = -1;
int avanzar = 0;
var campopartida="";
var camponombrepartida = "";

while (avanzar == 0)
{
    //para saber, posiblemente con mensajes despues o como querias en que fila se producen las incidencias
    fila = fila + 1;
    if ((oDs.Tables[0].Rows[fila][0]).ToString() == "")
    {
         avanzar = 1;
         break;
    }

    campopartida = (oDs.Tables[0].Rows[fila][0].ToString());
    camponombrepartida = oDs.Tables[0].Rows[fila][1].ToString();


}
```

Este código me resulta efectivo cuando empieza a leer desde la fila 2 del archivo excel, pero no me toma la primera fila. Deseo que la primera fila también se lea, ya que contiene datos y no encabezados.

Para tratar de solucionar este problema, estuve investigando que había que agregar el siguiente atributo `HDR=No` al string `conStr`, es decir así:

```
 conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                       "Data Source=" + Foldername + "" + filename + ";" +
                       "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" +
                        "HDR=No";
```

Pero al hacerlo me sale el siguiente error en oconn.Open();:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en System.Data.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>   Información adicional: No se pudo encontrar el archivo ISAM instalable.

Entonces intente tratar de agregar una fila adicional al inicio, y así leer desde la primera fila que tenía datos usando este código:

```
Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Importados/");
fileuploader.SaveAs(Foldername + filename.ToString());

String conStr = "";
switch (Extension)
{
     case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
         conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                  "Data Source=" + Foldername + "" + filename + ";" +
                  "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
         break;

     case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
         conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                  "Data Source=" + Foldername + "" + filename + ";" +
                  "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" +
                   "";
         break;
}
OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand();
//oconn.ConnectionString = conStr;


OleDbDataAdapter oDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();
//DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
oconn.ConnectionString = conStr;
oconn.Open();   
oCmd.Connection = oconn;
oDa.SelectCommand = oCmd;                      

oCmd.CommandText = "select * from [Hoja1$]";
//oDa.Fill(oDs);

DataTable dtDataTable = new DataTable();
using (OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(oCmd))
     oledbAdapter.Fill(dtDataTable);
string stRowNumber = (dtDataTable.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
string stRowID = "A" + stRowNumber + ":B" + stRowNumber;
oCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Hoja1$" + stRowID + "] SET F1=45, F2='54'";
oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//oCmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Hoja1$] ([Hoja1$A1:A1],[Hoja1$B1:B1]) values('7','e')";
//oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
oconn.Close();
```

Pero me salió el siguiente error en `oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`:

> No se han especificado valores para algunos de los parámetros requeridoSe produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en System.Data.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>   Información adicional: No se han especificado valores para algunos de los parámetros requeridos.

Ya estoy algo aburrido de tratar de solucionar, ya que las soluciones que aparecen en google no me dan dado resultado.

Espero poder contar con uds. recibir alguna idea o ayuda que me sea de utilidad.
Desde ya, gracias.

Nota: El archivo excel que trato de importar es de office 2016

Comment: Ya eres un usuario experimentado, te pediría por favor que trates de formatear tu pregunta lo mejor posible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las `Extended Properties` de la cadena de conexión deben estar entre comillas para que sean aceptadas, si no es así se lanza la excepción que especificas en primer lugar. Prueba tu primer código usando esto:

```
conStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"", Foldername + filename);
```